# Best method/workaround for mismatching protocols - communication between http/https

Tags: javascript, https, same-origin-policy, postmessage

I've looked at several methods, and I'm not sure which is the best approach.

I have 2 domains - exactly the same, except for differing protocols.

Parent page is on `http`, child iframe is on `https`.

I need to send 3 variables from the child to the parent.

What accomplishes this in the easiest manner? `postMessage` with IE7 fallback?
Such as: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

Or `jsonp`?

Comment: How can you use jsonp for iframe-communication?

Comment: @Bergi - http://snaggled.github.com/2010/04/08/Understanding-cross-domain-javascript.html

Comment: OK, seems you don't know it: JSONP is for getting information from other domains, and has nothing to to with iframes.

Comment: OK, but regardless - you could still use jsonp to communicate between protocols - if you can use it between domains, you can use it between parent page and child iframe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definetley go for `postMessage`.

Have a look at this [wrapper](http://postmessage.freebaseapps.com/). The fifth example on that page will show you how to pass data from the iframe to the parent window.